# ICMP Reply packet

Tags: c++, vb6, packet, icmp, reply

I wonder if you can generate an ICMP Reply packet using the APIs from icmp.dll ?
As of now, I was only able to send a standard Request packet using IcmpCreateFile, IcmpSendEcho and IcmpCloseHandle APIs.  Thanks.

Comment: Even if you could, how would that code work? The OS replies to the ping, your software can't "register" as being the ping reply application.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi   It can, if you use 3rd party driver like WinPCap for your purposes. I'm just trying to avoid that route and see if there are some hands on APIs available.  Otherwise I will have to design the whole packet myself, calculate IP and ICMP header checksums and so on..

Comment: You're missing my point. Let's say there's a library that will let you create the ICMP reply packet. How, without using WinPCap, et. al. will you be able to send this in response to an incoming ICMP packet?

Comment: I never said my aim was to respond to incoming ICMP packets, my general purpose is penetration testing.

Comment: In that case, you can ignore what I said. We get a lot of questions from people that don't know what they're trying to do or what they want to achieve, so I was just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use raw sockets (built into Windows XP+) or WinPcap to create custom packets.

Comment: you see, i need to send specially crafted ICMP packets to check for certain vulnerabilities on a certain device. I could easily do this on Linux or using third party driver like WinPcap on windows. But I was wondering if windows libraries provide such capability.

Comment: As I said, recent versions of Windows do, but require admin access. If you're happy with the answer, please click the tick to the left.

Comment: the recent versions of Windows do not have such capabilities. Raw sockets have limitations, even with elevated privileges. See "Limitations on Raw Sockets" here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx . WinPcap is an option I've mentioned in this thread myself, which I'm trying to avoid. So technically, I don't see any answers to my question.

Comment: It certainly appears they do from the article you linked and I don't see anything that disallows your stated question.